# Bug found in Golang Regexp ReplaceAllString?

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

const sample = `darted`

func main() {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`^(.*?)d(.*)$`)
    s := re.ReplaceAllString(sample, `$1c$2`)
    fmt.Println(s)//prints 'arted' expected: carted
}
```

Go playground: https://go.dev/play/p/-f0Cd_81eMX

Trying a non-alpha characters works (i.e. '$1.$2' results in '.arted')

Adding more than one alpha character works (i.e. '$1cl$2' results in 'clarted')

**Why doesn't the above sample work?**

Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong, or confirm this is a bug in Go that needs to be reported?

Comment: It is very unlikely you will find a bug in a mature language, especially in a commonly used core library  If you think you've found a bug in Go, it's 99.9999% likely a bug in your own code

Comment: `Adding more than one alpha character works (i.e. '$1cl$2' results in 'clarted')`, have you tried this? The result is `arted` instead of `clarted`.

Comment: What, only 6 nines? 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your replacement:

```
`$1c$2`
```

This is as interpreted as a capture group literally named `$1c` which doesn't exist in the regex. You want `${1}c`.

Comment: This is documented under [Expand](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp#Regexp.Expand), the second and especially third paragraphs.

Comment: To add to @hobbs (correct) comment: The `ReplaceAllString()` documentation says: “ReplaceAllString returns a copy of src, replacing matches of the Regexp with the replacement string repl. **Inside repl, $ signs are interpreted as in Expand**, so for instance $1 represents the text of the first submatch.” (emphasis mine)